# Is it possible to enumerate all available DDE servers with `TDdeClientConv` class?

Tags: delphi, vcl, dde

I was curious about all the running DDE servers, tried `TDdeClientConv` class but got confused with it (may be just didn't figured out how) and finally rolled my own low-level (normally applications should use DDEML abstraction layer) "client":

```
procedure TForm6.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { initiate DDE conversation with all top-level windows }
  SendMessage(
    HWND_BROADCAST,
    WM_DDE_INITIATE,
    Handle,
    MakeLParam(
      0,        // all services
      0         // all topics
    )
  );
end;

procedure TForm6.WMDDE_Ack(var Message: TWMDDE_Ack);
begin
  { this message handler receives acknowledgements }
  { and prints service-topic pairs to console }
  Writeln('"' + GetAtom(Message.App) + '"', #9, '"' + GetAtom(Message.Topic) + '"');
end;
```

Question: is it possible to do the same with `TDdeClientConv` class, that is, initiate a DDE conversation with all available services and receive multiple acknowledgements? Or `TDdeClientConv` merely represents client endpoint of DDE conversation and thus my scenario is out of the scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TDdeClientConv` does not use any window messages, it uses the [Dynamic Data Exchange Management Library (DDEML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648712.aspx) instead.  `TDdeClientConv` can connect only to a single server that implements a specified Service and/or Topic, as it establishes its connection using the DDEML [`DdeConnect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648745.aspx) function:

> Establishes a conversation with a server application that supports the specified service name and topic name pair. **If more than one such server exists, the system selects only one**.

DDEML's [`DdeConnectList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648746.aspx) function, on the other hand, can establish a conversation with multiple servers supporting a given Service and/or Topic.

> **Establishes a conversation with all server applications that support the specified service name and topic name pair**. An application can also use this function to obtain a list of conversation handles by passing the function an existing conversation handle. The Dynamic Data Exchange Management Library removes the handles of any terminated conversations from the conversation list. **The resulting conversation list contains the handles of all currently established conversations that support the specified service name and topic name**.

You can enumerate that list using the [`DdeQueryNextServer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648762.aspx) and [`DdeQueryConvInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648761.aspx) functions.